# how to install cc-mode-5.32.3? (hightling in C++ mode of emacs)

Tags: c++, emacs

I am editting my C++ program on a unix cluster by using emacs. I wanna emacs to highlight key words in C++. After searching online, I decide to install cc-mode-5.3.3. But I stuck here:

follow the readme instruction at http://cc-mode.sourceforge.net/src/README

After byte compiling, I don't understand

> Put the compiled files somewhere (X)Emacs will find them, i.e. in
>       some path that's in the load-path variable.  You must make sure
>       they are found before any CC Mode files which are distributed with
>       (X)Emacs.  A directory has higher precendence than all directories
>       after it in the load-path list.

Comment: I suggest you to dig into http://emacswiki.org/emacs/LoadPath . That's very easy: copy the file where emacs can find it, e.g. `~/.emacs.d`, but likely this is not good since it is looked after other dirs that might contain a CC mode.

Comment: I tried add the following line to the .emacs file
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/cc-mode-5.32.3/")
But it does not help.

Comment: 1) is you os a gnu/linux or alike? (hopefully yes if you get the `~`... 2) are your compiled elp or simply el inside that folder? 3) is that folder read before "site" folder where cc mode distributed with emacs is? (I daresay, it is not so) ...

Comment: 1) Os is a unix
2) I did this command " $emacs -batch -no-site-file -q -f batch-byte-compile cc-*.el " before  adding the following line to the .emacs file (add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/cc-mode-5.32.3/") 
3)I don't understand your third question.
Thanks!

Comment: By the way, right now, key words in Emacs is highlighted by underscore.

Answer (score 0):

GNU Emacs comes together with cc-mode installed by default, so you don't need to install it manually.  To enable symbols hightlighting, you need to set variable `global-font-lock-mode` to true value, for example, by using `M-x customize-variable global-font-lock-mode`, switching it to t, and pressing `Apply and Save`.

P.S. Are you running Emacs in console, or in graphical mode? If in console, then you could be need to setup corresponding font-lock faces. Use the `M-x customize-face` command to set faces whose names are starting with `font-lock-`

Comment: I am running Emacs in console. When I use my MAC to access the remote cluster, key words are highlighted. However when I use SSH on Windows to access the same cluster, all key words are gray and highlighted by underscore. So how can I fix it?

Comment: I think, that you need to set correct terminal type in putty this should be something like xterm, or something like - not all terminals have colors, some are emulating them with gray codes...

Comment: Do you mean there is no way to highlight key words for some terminal? Forget my few knowledge about this. Could you give me some clues to try it?

Comment: I'm not sure about windows terminal programs. Try to execute `export TERM=xterm` or `export TERM=xterm-color` before running emacs.